# Why is Matlab Function fft() not working for certain equations

Tags: matlab, fft, matlab-figure

I am trying to get the Fourier transform of a sinc function but I don't know why `fft()` (fast Fourier transform) is not working as it works for a basic sine function.

Here is my code, the plot produced is empty:

```
function fourier_transform

Ts= 1/50000;
t = 0:Ts:.5-Ts;
% p = sin(40*t);
m = sin(100*t)./(100*t);

f = fft(m);
plot(t,abs(f));

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m(1)` is computed by `sin(0)/0`, which equals `NaN`.

`NaN` means "Not a Number", and indicates an error situation. Any computation you do with `NaN` will propagate that `NaN`, to warn you that there was an error somewhere along the way when computing. For example, `sum(m)` equals `NaN`. Since each output element of the FFT involves computations with each input of `m`, all of those output elements will be `NaN` as well.

Your `f` is all `NaN`, and `plot` will just skip the `NaN` points, and so produces no output.

You can fix your computation in one of two ways:

1. Avoid the division by zero by dividing by `100*t + 1e-9`, the very small value added will prevent a zero but otherwise not affect other results.

   ```
    m = sin(100*t)./(100*t + 1e-9);
   ```
2. Know that `m(1)` involves a division by zero and fix it.

   ```
    m = sin(100*t)./(100*t);
    m(1) = 1;
   ```